# I select 1 face, but it selects multiple others?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

As the title suggests
Anyone one face I click, selects multiple others for no reason:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just gotta go to *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object and Data*
[image]

Comment: Sounds as if you've duplicated the faces using ALT-D instead of SHIFT-D.